# Get latitude and longitude from cellid, lac, MCC, MNC in ASP.NET webservice

Tags: asp.net, location, cellid

I have an .asmx webservice that gets the cellid, MCC, MNC and LAC and I want to use opencellid to get the latitude and longitude from these information, I didn't find resources in the internet, so I don't kow where to start. if you can help me to find out how to do that, or give me an alternative solution to find latitude and longitude from these informations it would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i face the same situation. read this.. answer is here. you can merge this code to your projecct..

http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/06/convert-celllocation-to-real-location.html

Answer (score 2):

How to get latitude and longitude from these parameters in a nice and elegant way using `GoogleMaps Api`.

I wrote A blog post about it here: [Blog Post](http://programmertoolbox.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-from-approximate-position-cellidlacmncmcc/)

Add this class to your project:

```
public class GoogleMapsApi
{
    static byte[] PostData(int MCC, int MNC, int LAC, int CID)
    {

        /* The shortCID parameter follows heuristic experiences:

         * Sometimes UMTS CIDs are build up from the original GSM CID (lower 4 hex digits)

         * and the RNC-ID left shifted into the upper 4 digits.

         */

        byte[] pd = new byte[] {

    0x00, 0x0e,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x1b,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x11

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x15

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x19

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x1f

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x23

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x27

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x2b

    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

};

        bool isUMTSCell = ((Int64)CID > 65535);

    /*    if (shortCID)

            CID &= 0xFFFF;      /* Attempt to resolve the cell using the

                        GSM CID part */

        if ((Int64)CID > 65536) /* GSM: 4 hex digits, UTMS: 6 hex

                        digits */

            pd[0x1c] = 5;

        else

            pd[0x1c] = 3;

        pd[0x11] = (byte)((MNC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x12] = (byte)((MNC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x13] = (byte)((MNC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x14] = (byte)((MNC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x15] = (byte)((MCC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x16] = (byte)((MCC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x17] = (byte)((MCC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x18] = (byte)((MCC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x27] = (byte)((MNC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x28] = (byte)((MNC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x29] = (byte)((MNC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2a] = (byte)((MNC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2b] = (byte)((MCC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2c] = (byte)((MCC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2d] = (byte)((MCC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2e] = (byte)((MCC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x1f] = (byte)((CID >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x20] = (byte)((CID >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x21] = (byte)((CID >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x22] = (byte)((CID >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x23] = (byte)((LAC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x24] = (byte)((LAC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x25] = (byte)((LAC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x26] = (byte)((LAC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        return pd;

    }

    static public string[] GetLatLng(int MCC, int MNC, int LAC, int CID)
    {

        string[] result = new string[2];

        try
        {

            String url = "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(

                new Uri(url));

            req.Method = "POST";

            byte[] pd = PostData(MCC, MNC, LAC, CID);

            req.ContentLength = pd.Length;

            req.ContentType = "application/binary";

            Stream outputStream = req.GetRequestStream();

            outputStream.Write(pd, 0, pd.Length);

            outputStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            byte[] ps = new byte[res.ContentLength];

            int totalBytesRead = 0;

            while (totalBytesRead < ps.Length)
            {

                totalBytesRead += res.GetResponseStream().Read(

                    ps, totalBytesRead, ps.Length - totalBytesRead);

            }

            if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                short opcode1 = (short)(ps[0] << 8 | ps[1]);

                byte opcode2 = ps[2];

                int ret_code = (int)((ps[3] << 24) | (ps[4] << 16) |

                               (ps[5] << 8) | (ps[6]));

                if (ret_code == 0)
                {

                    double lat = ((double)((ps[7] << 24) | (ps[8] << 16)

                                 | (ps[9] << 8) | (ps[10]))) / 1000000;

                    double lon = ((double)((ps[11] << 24) | (ps[12] <<

                                 16) | (ps[13] << 8) | (ps[14]))) /

                                 1000000;

                    result[0] = lat.ToString();
                    result[1] = lon.ToString();
                    return result;

                }

                else
                {

                    return result;
                }

            }

            else

                return result;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result[0] = ex.Message;
            return result;

        }

    }
}
```

Call the class to get the latitude and logitude wherever you want:

```
string[] s = GoogleMapsApi.GetLatLng(MCC, MNC, lac, cellid);
double lat = 0;
Boolean b1 = double.TryParse(s[0], out lat);
double lon = 0;
Boolean b2 = double.TryParse(s[1], out lon);
```

Comment: Link is broken. Cant visit that page.